# How to use typings-for-css-modules-loader and use indexed property

Tags: typescript

I'm using typings-for-css-modules-loader to generate typescript for my CSS modules. In general it's working great.  I have an import statement like this:

```
import * as styles from './MyStyles.scss'
```

And then I can use it in my JSX like this:

```
<div className={styles.cardBody}>
```

Excellent!  I have a scenario where I want to pass in a string to a function and index into the available styles.  Something like this:

```
const getStyle = (styleName: string) => {
        return `otherClass1 otherClass2 ${styles[styleName]}`
    }
```

Typescript isn't happy with this:

```
${styles[styleName]}
```

It complains:

```
Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 'string' can't be used to index type 'typeof import("<path to scss file>")'.
  No index signature with a parameter of type 'string' was found on type 'typeof import("<path to scss file>")'.
```

How can I make typescript happy, short of using ts-ignore?  Assuming there isn't a better way, I'd be okay with losing some type safety if I had to cast to any somehow (which I'm not sure how to do).

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, I don't know how to avoid this behavior. Even this simple code returns your error:

```
const styles = {style_main: 'fgsfds'}
const styleName = 'main'
console.log(styles[`style_${styleName}`])
```

while `console.log(styles['style_main'])` works well.

As potentially dangerous workaround you can use `"suppressImplicitAnyIndexErrors": true` in tsconfig.json to disable this check globally.